# Automatically copy PDF.plugin to Chromium.app

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx, chrome

I'm using Chromatic.app to update my Chromium.app recently.

I'd like to use Chrome.app's PDF.plugin in Chromium.app.

Therefore I need to copy PDF.plugin to the following directory:

```
/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/Versions/$VERSION/Chromium\ Framework.framework/Internet\ Plug-Ins/
```

Maybe you guys have an idea for a bash-script (or something else) which runs after Chromatic.app updated my chromium and copies PDF.plugin to the new Chromium-Internet-Plug-Ins-directory.

The clue here is, that the version-number ("$VERSION" in my path above) always changes...

Comment: can you give me the directory that the chrome plugin is in (unfortunately my normal linux box is not working right now, I'm on windows).

Comment: Also, what OS are you on?

Comment: oops sorry, didn't see the OSX tag =)

Comment: @evamvid `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/$VERSION/Google\ Chrome\ Framework.framework/Internet\ Plug-Ins/`

Comment: @evamvid In my case I don't use Google Chrome. My PDF.plugin-directory is located at `@HOME/src/PDF.plugin` ...

Comment: wait....in `@HOME/src/PDF.plugin` do you already have a copy of the plugin?

Comment: I'll go ahead and update to use that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make and run this script? Since I didn't have the directory of your Chrome installation, I used `wget` to download a copy of the plugin I found on the Net, but it's better to keep everything local, so if you provide the directory, I'll update it to use that instead. Anyway, here goes. Let me know if anything goes wrong.

Just put this into a .sh file, and run it (you might have to use a sudo, or mess with file permissions/ownership)

UPDATE: Seems there is no chromium command line start under OSX, so I've updated the script to take user input to get the version number. I've commented out the code that came before for anybody who might have a similar problem on a Linux system, or just for future reference.

UPDATE2: I now have the directory where the plugin is (I think). I've commented out the `wget`. Here, I'm going under the assumption that the plugin won't be updated in this case; if I'm mistaken, I can have it link to the file instead of copying it.
Here goes!

```
#!/bin/bash
#result=$(chromium --version)
#arr=( $result )
#version=( ${arr[1]} )
echo "Type the Chromium version number that you want to use."
read version
cd /Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/Versions/$version/Chromium\ Framework.framework/Internet\ Plug-Ins/
#wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20230522/docs/libpdf.so
cp @HOME/src/PDF.plugin/libpdf.so /Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/Versions/$version/Chromium\ Framework.framework/Internet\ Plug-Ins/
echo "finished!"
```

Turns out, you were actually very close when you used `$VERSION` as a placeholder!

Let me know if anything goes wrong.

After running the script, you'll need to (in Chromium) navigate to `chrome://plugins/`. 
Then, enable the plugin.

It (should) work after that.

If you post the directory of your Chrome installation (or even if you download Chrome, extract those plugins, and delete Chrome, and give us that directory), I can make it use Chrome's Flash player and FFMPEG plugins as well. This is important because Flash support for Linux is ending (see [this story from 2012](http://www.linuxinsider.com/story/74541.html). The last version was 11.2.

Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll get the other plugins and try that! : )

Comment: Seems in OSX there is no `chromium` via command line... : /

Comment: hmmm....how would it be if you typed in the version number? I'm sad  though; I was quite proud of that string-to-array-and-back-again bit! I'm just learning Bash...